# When I create a new app in rails on c9.io , then runs the server it didn't run?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

> Expected string default value for '--rc'; got false (boolean)
>       Usage:
>         rails new APP_PATH [options]

```
Options:


 -r, [--ruby=PATH]                                  enter code here    # Path to the Ruby binary of your choice
                                                         # Default: /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby
  -m, [--template=TEMPLATE]                              # Path to some application template (can be a filesystem path or URL)
      [--skip-gemfile], [--no-skip-gemfile]              # Don't create a Gemfile
  -B, [--skip-bundle], [--no-skip-bundle]                # Don't run bundle install
  -G, [--skip-git], [--no-skip-git]                      # Skip .gitignore file
      [--skip-keeps], [--no-skip-keeps]                  # Skip source control .keep files
  -O, [--skip-active-record], [--no-skip-active-record]  # Skip Active Record files
  -S, [--skip-sprockets], [--no-skip-sprockets]          # Skip Sprockets files
      [--skip-spring], [--no-skip-spring]                # Don't install Spring application preloader
  -d, [--database=DATABASE]                              # Preconfigure for selected database (options: mysql/oracle/postgresql/sqlite3/frontbase/ibm_db/sqlserver/jdbcmysql/jdbcsqlite3/jdbcpostgresql/jdbc)
                                                         # Default: sqlite3
  -j, [--javascript=JAVASCRIPT]                          # Preconfigure for selected JavaScript library
                                                         # Default: jquery
  -J, [--skip-javascript], [--no-skip-javascript]        # Skip JavaScript files
      [--dev], [--no-dev]                                # Setup the application with Gemfile pointing to your Rails checkout
      [--edge], [--no-edge]                              # Setup the application with Gemfile pointing to Rails repository
      [--skip-turbolinks], [--no-skip-turbolinks]        # Skip turbolinks gem
  -T, [--skip-test-unit], [--no-skip-test-unit]          # Skip Test::Unit files
      [--rc=RC]                                          # Path to file containing extra configuration options for rails command
      [--no-rc], [--no-no-rc]                            # Skip loading of extra configuration options from .railsrc file

Runtime options:
  -f, [--force]                    # Overwrite files that already exist
  -p, [--pretend], [--no-pretend]  # Run but do not make any changes
  -q, [--quiet], [--no-quiet]      # Suppress status output
  -s, [--skip], [--no-skip]        # Skip files that already exist

Rails options:
  -h, [--help], [--no-help]        # Show this help message and quit
  -v, [--version], [--no-version]  # Show Rails version number and quit
```

> Description:
>           The 'rails new' command creates a new Rails application with a default
>           directory structure and configuration at the path you specify.
>
> ```
>     You can specify extra command-line arguments to be used every time
>     'rails new' runs in the .railsrc configuration file in your home
> ```

directory.

```
    Note that the arguments specified in the .railsrc file don't affect the
    defaults values shown above in this help message.

Example:
    rails new ~/Code/Ruby/weblog

    This generates a skeletal Rails installation in ~/Code/Ruby/weblog.
    See the README in the newly created application to get going.


Process exited with code: 0
```

Comment: Did you try `rails s -p $PORT -b $IP` ?

Comment: Yes,I have tried it but not working.

Comment: You post literally just contains the `rails` help text. Please describe what exactly you tried. Also what does "then runs the server it didn't run?" mean?

Comment: Are you in the correct directory when trying to run the server? (forgive me if this is basic, but just trying to eliminate it)

Comment: Bro! I have opened c9.io,then created the workspace,then run the project,it diplayed the above error message(in my Question)!,I have also tried it with rails s -p $PORT -b but still not working!

Answer (score 0):

You may be calling "rails server" not from the directory in which your Rails app resides. Makes sure you "cd" to the correct directory before calling "rails server".